# c# Parallel For loop with minute delay

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, parallel.for

I have a very simple for loop that looks like this

```
for(int i = 0; i< 26; i++)
{
    DoSomething(i);
}
```

The DoSomething function takes about ~3 minutes to execute. I want to write a for loop that calls DoSomething() every minute without waiting for the previous call to finish. I tried to do something like this:

```
Parallel.For(0, 26, i =>
{
    DoSomething(i);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
}
```

But it does not work since it first does the call and then sleeps. Reversing the steps also means that the DoSomething method calls fire without delay in between each call. How do I set it up so that the call to DoSomething is every minute?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: So you want something to be processed in parallel and after a particular time interval? Correct? If yes, see @MichaelTodd 's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which internally uses a `Timer` object:

```
public async Task DoSomethingAndWaitAsync()
{
    int i = 0
    while (i < 26)
    {
        Task.Run(() => DoSomething(i));
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        i++;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to keep the `for` loop:

```
public async Task DoSomethingAndWaitAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        Task.Run(() => DoSomething(i));
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026042/wait-for-response-from-the-serial-port-and-then-send-next-data

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++)
{
    Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            DoSomething(i);
        }
    );

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}
```

Comment: Whether or not you view this as "wasting" a thread depends on context, and adding async/await as needed is trivial.